# How can I implement reddit style sub instances of my website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain, reddit

I have a website that I made using ruby on rails at www.tradespring.net. I want to create a bunch of instances, like www.tradespring.net/electronics, www.tradespring.net/automotive, ect. where these sub-sites work exactly the same as the original but each have their own set of posts, but users are the same across all sub-instances.

Where could I start looking? I don't even know good keywords to google at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with two best webcasts created by Ryan lately which explains creating multitenancy application in Rails.

```
Multitenancy with Scopes
Webcast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes
Source Code: https://github.com/railscasts/388-multitenancy-with-scopes

Multitenancy with PostgreSQL
Webcast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql
Source Code: https://github.com/railscasts/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql
```

**[update]** Oh! I missed that these are pro webcasts. Though you can check source code of these webcasts.

Comment: It's worth it. You must give it a try, just $9 per month.